# Markov Chain expected number of visits

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, canonical-transformation

\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&.2&.8&0\\ 
0&0&0&.9&.1\\ 
.6&0&0&0&.4\\
.2&.8&0&0&0\\
0&.9&.1&0&0
 \end{pmatrix}

Question: Suppose the Markov Chain Starts at state C. What is the expected number of visits to state B before reaching state A.

My professor showed several ways to solve problems similar to these but I am on with this one.

I have tried put the matrix into canonical form and using that to solve for the Q matrix, but I am running into issues doing that.

Comment: Why the matrix is not square?

Comment: What is state $A$, $B$ and $C$?

Comment: The matrix was not displayed correctly sorry for that, it has been updated

Comment: For example P11 would be going from State A to State A, P12 would be going from State A to State B

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is make the state $A$ absorbing and then calculate the fundamental matrix $N = (I-Q)^{-1}$ where $Q$ is the block with state $A$ removed (assuming you indexed the matrix with states $A, B, C, D, E$)

$$ Q=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&.9&.1 \\
0&0&0&.4 \\
.8&0&0&0 \\
.9&.1&0&.4
\end{bmatrix}
$$

You get

$$N= \frac{5}{447}
\begin{bmatrix}
480 & 5 & 432 & 50 \\
\color{red}{180} & 95 & 162 & 56 \\
384 & 4 & 435 & 40 \\
450 & 14 & 405 & 140
\end{bmatrix}$$

This matrix $N$ encodes the expected number of visits to each state $i=B, C, D, E$ when starting from state $j=B, C, D, E$ before being absorbed. So you can read the answer is $\frac{5\times180}{447} = \frac{300}{149}$.

Comment: I had the wrong index in the solution (I fixed it). We want visits to B, and it is in the first index in the $N$-matrix, so we should look at the number $180$.